# Android: operation time out when web service called

Tags: android, web-services, timeout, device, ksoap2

I'm calling a web service from Android application. When I use AVD it's all right and I have response from server, but when I run on my real device (HTC), I get "The operation time out".
The Internet speed on device is good, for example Google Maps are loading very fast.

To connect with server I use ksoap2:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(getString(R.string.NAMESPACE), getString(R.string.METHOD_NAME)); 

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
            new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
        envelope.dotNet = true;


envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
int Timeout = 10000;
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(FullURL, Timeout);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(getString(R.string.SOAP_ACTION), envelope);           
            return envelope.getResponse().toString();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            return ("ERROR:" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

URL contains the server's IP like

> http://46.146.120.165/RouteGen/Service.asmx

Why there's a time out error on real device and how to force it to work normally?

Comment: The situation was in a port 80. I created a rule for it in windows firewall, and it's all right with web method calling from Android device now!

Comment: Can you say the way you solved this problem clearly. If I change the port which is not 80. Is it Ok?. Waiting for you answer, llya Blokh. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the connection time out and socket timeout for real life devices. You has to set the timeout values appropriately. After that time out an exception will be recieved, catch that exception and show an alert like "Bad network".

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 10000);
int timeoutSocket = 60*1000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
```

Comment: I add Android code to my first post. U see I added Timeout parameter in HttpTransportSE.. but it didn't help.

Comment: @IIya Blokh -- Don't kno about the httptransportse. MAy be it's setting only the connection time out not the data time out.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem. The solution I found was that the phone uses WiFi or 3g connections, and the web service I was referring had some kind of firewall.

So, I replaced the IP address in the URL (example: 'http://10.0.0.0') with a hostname (example: 'http://abc.com').

Answer (score 0):

I face this situation while developing my project and found the solution which I describe below :

Please turn off your Windows Firewall from `Control Panel -> Windows Firewall and click on Turns Windows Firewall on or off to turn off your Windows Firewall.`

Then your application works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the similar issue by creating a rule in Firewall on my development machine to allow remote connections on port 80.

Answer (score -1):

I got this type of error when I was testing my application on local server.I used IP address of the system,it works fine.If anyone got same issue,please check IP address of your url first.Hope this help others who are testing there application on local server.

Yesterday I was using this link for web service called http://192.168.1.7/DemoAndroid/Loginwebservice.php?username=john&dob=1234.
 and it work fine,but today when I used same link it give me error

> operation time out

so I checked my system IP address and It was not same as mentioned in url.so I copied that IP address and Paste in above url and it works again.

Comment: this is not answer. either add more description to answer why OP getting issue or how your answer help in resolving or  comment it  in post